# Could not locate C:\Xilinx\xic\bin\xic.bat

Tags: xilinx, vivado

I used Xilinx to install Vivado, for a college project, but then after uninstalling it I was unable to get rid of this error that pops up every time I start my laptop. Has anyone else been in this situation?

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4fEb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely in the 'Startup' folder of your start menu. Start Task Manager and click on the Startup tab and disable it from there, or delete it from your profile directory in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.